# Stored Procedure, registrar datos con auto increment

Tags: sql

tengo una duda, existe la posibilidad de crear un SP, en SQL, que tenga un auto increment en el Primary Key?

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
USE DBMovies
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE spNuevaPelicula
    @idP NUMERIC (4),
    @tituloP VARCHAR(40),
    @actorP VARCHAR(40),
    @idG NUMERIC(2,0),
    @idC VARCHAR(1),
    @idSt NUMERIC(1,0),
    @precioP NUMERIC(6,2)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT P.idP 'ID', P.tituloP 'Titulo', P.actorP 'Actor', 
           G.descG 'Genero', C.descC 'Clasificación', E.descSt 'Estatus',
           P.precioP 'Precio'
    FROM Pelicula P INNER JOIN Genero G ON P.idG = G.idG
                    INNER JOIN Clasificacion C ON P.idC = C.idC
                    INNER JOIN Estatus E ON P.idSt = E.idSt
    INSERT INTO Pelicula (idP, tituloP, actorP, idG, idC, idSt, precioP)
    VALUES (@idP, @tituloP, @actorP, @idG, @idC, @idSt, @precioP)
END
GO
```

Existe alguna forma de ingresar el MAX(idP) +1 o bien a lo que estuve investigando se tendria que modificar la tabla y colocar el IDENTITY?
Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un nivel de transacción serializable.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spNuevaPelicula
    @idP NUMERIC (4),
    @tituloP VARCHAR(40),
    @actorP VARCHAR(40),
    @idG NUMERIC(2,0),
    @idC VARCHAR(1),
    @idSt NUMERIC(1,0),
    @precioP NUMERIC(6,2)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

    INSERT INTO Pelicula (idP, tituloP, actorP, idG, idC, idSt, precioP)
    VALUES ((SELECT ISNULL(max(idP),0)+1 FROM Pelicula), @tituloP, @actorP, @idG, @idC, @idSt, @precioP);

END
GO
```

Eso te garantiza el último id, pero no la consecutividad de los id,s.
Identity no garantiza ni una cosa ni otra.

[Set transaction isolation level](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[Id,s incrementales](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/23/id-incremental-como/)

[Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funciono, le dare una revisada a la doc, saludos!